# Possible to set datasource of Windows.Forms.Charts to DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

In my `Windows Form`, Is it possible to set `windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart` to a `datatable`, `dataset`, or other datasource? I've searched, but I've only seen how to manually plot points.

For example, let's say my `datatable` has something like this:

```
Model    Inventory
Volvo    20
Ford     15
Toyota   30
Mazda    28
```

And I want to create a barchart out of that datatable, can I just bind it and cofigure the chart? Or is it more time-consuming than that?

Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely.  There's a tutorial on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: And a [blog on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexgor/2009/02/20/data-binding-microsoft-chart-control/)